# EF6 generating empty child entity for nullable foreign key

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have been struggling with this problem for the past couple of days.  I have a web application that communicates to a WebAPI API to retrieve and update entities that are created and maintained by the "Entity Framework Reverse POCO CodeFirst Generator" visual studio extension.  They all seem to generate the entities and the DbContext just fine.  But here is the problem:  The web client makes an ajax call to an API method that returns a "Patient" entity back.  This Patient Entity have a couple of nullable Foreign keys namely LanguageId and PharmacyId.  Now, when the Patient is retrieved by the repository, it looks fine on the server [image: Error screen shot 1].  The LanguageId and the PharmacyId are null as expected. The Navigation properties of Patient, namely luLanguage and Pharmacy are also rightly set to null.  The json object received by the client also looks fine at this time [image: Error Screen shot 2].  Both the foreign key Ids and the navigation properties are null.  The client does some optional edits to the patient object and POSTs the object back to the server.  Just before the POST ajax call is made, the Patient json object still looks fine as expected [image: Error Screen shot 3].  The foreign keys and the navigation properties are null.  But as soon as that object is received by the WebAPI method, strangely, there are empty Language and Pharmacy Navigation Properties [image: Error Screen shot 4].  The the primary keys corresponding to the foreign keys are INT, they are initialized with 0.  This makes the DbContext mad when it tries to update them, because the foreign key for Language and the primary key in the Language navigation object don't match.  One is null and the other is 0 (zero).  I have tried so many different tests but no matter how I cut it, I come back to the same problem.

Here is the Entity model builder configuration code.

```
public PatientConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("Patient", schema);
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName(@"ID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.LastName).HasColumnName(@"LastName").IsOptional().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(x => x.FirstName).HasColumnName(@"FirstName").IsOptional().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(x => x.MiddleName).HasColumnName(@"MiddleName").IsOptional().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(30);
        Property(x => x.Gender).HasColumnName(@"Gender").IsOptional().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(18);
        Property(x => x.Dob).HasColumnName(@"DOB").IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");
        Property(x => x.SocialSecurity).HasColumnName(@"SocialSecurity").IsOptional().HasColumnType("varbinary");
        Property(x => x.LastFourSsn).HasColumnName(@"LastFourSSN").IsOptional().HasColumnType("int");
        Property(x => x.PharmacyId).HasColumnName(@"PharmacyID").IsOptional().HasColumnType("bigint");
        Property(x => x.InUseById).HasColumnName(@"InUseByID").IsOptional().HasColumnType("bigint");
        Property(x => x.LanguageId).HasColumnName(@"LanguageID").IsOptional().HasColumnType("int");
        Property(x => x.Status).HasColumnName(@"Status").IsOptional().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(10);
        Property(x => x.IsInactive).HasColumnName(@"IsInactive").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bit");
        Property(x => x.CreatedById).HasColumnName(@"CreatedByID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint");
        Property(x => x.CreatedDate).HasColumnName(@"CreatedDate").IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");
        Property(x => x.UpdatedById).HasColumnName(@"UpdatedByID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint");
        Property(x => x.UpdatedDate).HasColumnName(@"UpdatedDate").IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");
        Property(x => x.MigratedBy).HasColumnName(@"MigratedBy").IsOptional().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(10);
        Property(x => x.TimeStamped).HasColumnName(@"TimeStamped").IsRequired().IsFixedLength().HasColumnType("timestamp").HasMaxLength(8).IsRowVersion().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

        // Foreign keys
        HasOptional(a => a.LuLanguage).WithMany(b => b.Patients).HasForeignKey(c => c.LanguageId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_Patient_luLanguage
        HasOptional(a => a.Pharmacy).WithMany(b => b.Patients).HasForeignKey(c => c.PharmacyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_Pharmacy_Patient
        InitializePartial();
    }
```

And here is the generated Patient Entity

```
public partial class Patient : EntityBase
{
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; } // ID (Primary key)
    public string LastName { get; set; } // LastName (length: 50)
    public string FirstName { get; set; } // FirstName (length: 50)
    public string MiddleName { get; set; } // MiddleName (length: 30)
    public string Gender { get; set; } // Gender (length: 18)
    public System.DateTime Dob { get; set; } // DOB
    public byte[] SocialSecurity { get; set; } // SocialSecurity
    public int? LastFourSsn { get; set; } // LastFourSSN
    public long? PharmacyId { get; set; } // PharmacyID
    public long? InUseById { get; set; } // InUseByID
    public int? LanguageId { get; set; } // LanguageID
    public string Status { get; set; } // Status (length: 10)
    public bool IsInactive { get; set; } // IsInactive
    public long CreatedById { get; set; } // CreatedByID
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } // CreatedDate
    public long UpdatedById { get; set; } // UpdatedByID
    public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; } // UpdatedDate
    public string MigratedBy { get; set; } // MigratedBy (length: 10)
    public byte[] TimeStamped { get; private set; } // TimeStamped (length: 8)

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<AuditPatientChange> AuditPatientChanges { get; set; } // auditPatientChange.R_88
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientAddress> PatientAddresses { get; set; } // PatientAddress.FK_PatientAddress_Patient
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientCallTracking> PatientCallTrackings { get; set; } // PatientCallTracking.R_74
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientContact> PatientContacts { get; set; } // PatientContact.FK_PatientContact_Patient
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientCreditCard> PatientCreditCards { get; set; } // PatientCreditCard.R_59
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientDiseaseState> PatientDiseaseStates { get; set; } // PatientDiseaseState.R_65
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientIcd10> PatientIcd10 { get; set; } // PatientICD10.R_63
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientMedicalHistory> PatientMedicalHistories { get; set; } // PatientMedicalHistory.R_60
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientNoteAndComment> PatientNoteAndComments { get; set; } // PatientNoteAndComment.R_73
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientPayment> PatientPayments { get; set; } // PatientPayment.R_56
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientPlanPolicy> PatientPlanPolicies { get; set; } // PatientPlanPolicy.R_90
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientReferral> PatientReferrals { get; set; } // PatientReferral.FK_PatientReferral_Patient
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PatientShareOfCost> PatientShareOfCosts { get; set; } // PatientShareOfCost.R_62
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Rx> Rxes { get; set; } // Rx.FK_Rx_Patient

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual LuLanguage LuLanguage { get; set; } // FK_Patient_luLanguage
    public virtual Pharmacy Pharmacy { get; set; } // FK_Pharmacy_Patient

    public Patient()
    {
        IsInactive = false;
        CreatedById = 0;
        UpdatedById = 0;
        AuditPatientChanges = new System.Collections.Generic.List<AuditPatientChange>();
        PatientAddresses = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientAddress>();
        PatientCallTrackings = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientCallTracking>();
        PatientContacts = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientContact>();
        PatientCreditCards = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientCreditCard>();
        PatientDiseaseStates = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientDiseaseState>();
        PatientIcd10 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientIcd10>();
        PatientMedicalHistories = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientMedicalHistory>();
        PatientNoteAndComments = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientNoteAndComment>();
        PatientPayments = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientPayment>();
        PatientPlanPolicies = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientPlanPolicy>();
        PatientReferrals = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientReferral>();
        PatientShareOfCosts = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientShareOfCost>();
        Rxes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Rx>();
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

and here is the client side javascript code to test out this problem:

```
function testx1(){

var patient;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/api/patient/patient/61143",
    success: function (result) {
        patient = result;
        testx2(patient);
    },
    error: function (xhr, options, error) {
        debugger;
        alert(error);
    }
});
}

function testx2(patient) {
    patient.LastFourSsn = 5555;
    patient.ObjectStateEnum = 2;
    var x = "adsf";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/api/patient/patient",
        data: patient,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (xhr, options, error) {
        }
     });
}
```

My WebAPI code:

```
        [Route("patient/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetPatientByIdAsync( long id )
    {
        try
        {
            var patient = await patientService.GetPatientByIdAsync( id );
            if ( patient == null )
                return NotFound();
            return Ok( patient );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }

    [Route("patient")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SavePatient( Patient patient )
    {
        try
        {
            //if ( patient.LanguageId == null && patient.LuLanguage?.Id == 0 )
            //  patient.LuLanguage = null;
            //if ( patient.PharmacyId == null && patient.Pharmacy?.Id == 0 )
            //  patient.Pharmacy = null;
            IOperationStatus result = await patientService.UpdateAndSavePatientAsync(patient);
            if ( !result.Success )
                return InternalServerError( new Exception( result.Message ) );
            else
                return Ok();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Json serializer settings:

```
    public class BrowserJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public BrowserJsonFormatter()
    {
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add( new MediaTypeHeaderValue( "text/html" ) );
        this.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders( Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType )
    {
        base.SetDefaultContentHeaders( type, headers, mediaType );
        headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue( "application/json" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also include your actual webapi method code?

Comment: @Wiktor : I have edited my post to include the WebAPI methods code.  Thanks.

Comment: So when you call `SavePatient`, the bound parameter `patient` has already wrong values (0 instead of null)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I check the patient object on the client right before the post method is called and it looks OK.  luLanguage is null.  But when the call reaches the server API, luLanguage is not null but an empty object with id 0.  Strange, I know.  For love of god, I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Can you sniff the actual traffic between the client and the server with a http debugger to be 100% sure the entity goes with both nulls over the wire? Can't spot anything obvious here. Maybe there is something in the InitializePartial either in the entity or the mapping?

Comment: InitializePartial is empty.  This method was automatically generated by the POCO generator.  I have already checked the packet using fiddler and it is packaged as null for both Language and Pharmacy.  I don't know how an empty child is added when it reaches the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make couple of changes to my problem to get it solved.  First, I had to do a JSON.stringify on my json object that was about to be POSTed back to the server for update along with specifically mentioning "contentType: 'application/json'" in in the ajax post.  Secondly, I had to go with the VS built in ADO.NET Entity Data Model extension to generate my DbContext instead of using the Entity Framework Reverse POCO Generator.  With both these changes, things started to work.  I am sure if I dig deep into the dbContext code generated by both these tools, I might find the reason why my timestamp (rowversion) column was not properly received by my WebAPI method.  But since I was in a time crunch, I had to put off the investigation for another day.  It works now and thats all matters, at least for now.  Thanks all for trying to help.

EDIT: Just in case others come up against the same problem, here is what I found out after two agonizing days trying to fix this problem. It turns out that the "Entity Framework Reverse POCO Generator" creates the rowversion property with {get; **private** set} and rightly so. But when the WebAPI method receives the POST request, the process cannot, presumably, generate the Entity Class from the json and set the timestamp column with the value.  So, I edited the .tt file to let timestamp column have public get and set {get;set;}.  This fixed all my problems.  I still would have liked the private setter for the rowversion (timestamp) column and set the value somehow.  But due to the time crunch, I will just settle for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue has to do with how you are serializing the object.

To confirm this, manually add the Language and LanguageLu properties to your POST.

```
function testx2(patient) {
patient.LastFourSsn = 5555;
patient.ObjectStateEnum = 2;
patient.LuLanguage = null;
patient.Language = null;
var x = "adsf";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/api/patient/patient",
    data: patient,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function (xhr, options, error) {
    }
 });
```

}

If this works OK, then we can be fairly confident that there is an issue with the serialization of the patient object and you should post the code for the JSON serializer you are using.

Else I would look further into the fluent API syntax.

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited my post to show my serialization settings.  As for your answer, patient.LuLanguage is already null when received by testx2(patient) javascript function.  So, I would assume that I don't need to set it again manually.  Even if this works, I don't want to go that route because I have more than 100 entities used by client method such as this.  Also, many of them have deeply nested navigation properties.  It would be counter productive to set them all manually on the client.  So, I need to find a better solution/approach.

Comment: @BabuMannavalappil This is meant for diagnostic purposes only. It looks like the Json (de)serializer initializes default objects.